# syntax error with IF statement

Tags: ajax, forms, if-statement

This is a typicall registration form to a php server. I am trying to make an IF statement so no text field can be empty before submitting the form. Something is not working.

I dont get any syntax error but, even when I am writing on all fields I still cant submit to server.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#registrate').click(function (/*e*/)// e för att kunna sätta sub
 {
    var fields =$('input[type="text"]').not(":eq(0)")
    fields.each(function()
    {
   if
   ($(this).val() > "")
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'register.php',
        data:{
          name:$('#name').val(),
          username:$('#user').val(),   
          password:$('#show, #dold').val(),
          street:$('#street').val(),
          postal:$('#postal').val(),
          city:$('#city').val()
        },
        success: function(m) {$('#messphp')
        .text(m).fadeIn('slow');}
      });

 });

}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `;` after the if. Remove it.

if statements can't have ; at the end:

```
if(someCondition); is not valid
```